# Sequence contains no elements when querying XML file by attribute ID

Tags: c#, xml, regex, linq

I'm having a slightly confusing problem with my linq query against an XML file. It returns one of the nodes, by attribute value, correctly (`GB`). However, when I supply a different attribute value, for example: `JE` I receive a `sequence contains no elements` error, yet the element is clearly present in the XML doc?

This is my query:

```
return (from n in xml.Descendants("postalCodeData")
        where n.Element("postCodeRegex").Attribute("territoryId").Value == isoCode
        select n.Element("postCodeRegex").Value).Single().ToString();
```

Here is some sample XML data:

```
<postalCodeData>
  <postCodeRegex territoryId="GB" >GIR[ ]?0AA|((AB|AL|B|BA|BB|BD|BH|BL|BN|BR|BS|BT|CA|CB|CF|CH|CM|CO|CR|CT|CV|CW|DA|DD|DE|DG|DH|DL|DN|DT|DY|E|EC|EH|EN|EX|FK|FY|G|GL|GY|GU|HA|HD|HG|HP|HR|HS|HU|HX|IG|IM|IP|IV|JE|KA|KT|KW|KY|L|LA|LD|LE|LL|LN|LS|LU|M|ME|MK|ML|N|NE|NG|NN|NP|NR|NW|OL|OX|PA|PE|PH|PL|PO|PR|RG|RH|RM|S|SA|SE|SG|SK|SL|SM|SN|SO|SP|SR|SS|ST|SW|SY|TA|TD|TF|TN|TQ|TR|TS|TW|UB|W|WA|WC|WD|WF|WN|WR|WS|WV|YO|ZE)(\d[\dA-Z]?[ ]?\d[ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}))|BFPO[ ]?\d{1,4}</postCodeRegex>
  <postCodeRegex territoryId="JE" >JE\d[\dA-Z]?[ ]?\d[ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}</postCodeRegex>
  <postCodeRegex territoryId="GG" >GY\d[\dA-Z]?[ ]?\d[ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}</postCodeRegex>
</postalCodeData>
```

Can anyone spot what I've done wrong here? Why would this work for `GB` and not the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n.Element("postCodeRegex")
```

will return the first element of that type, and only its "territoryId" will be examined.

instead replace the where clause with this this :

```
 where n.Elements("postCodeRegex").Any(element=>element.Attribute("territoryId").Value == isoCode)
```

EDIT: 
Ok, so you wanted the matching postcoderegex item. I thought you wanted the first element that was bundled with a match. 
Then the solution is much easier.

```
return (from n in xml.Descendants("postCodeRegex")
  where n.Attribute("territoryId").Value == isoCode
  select n.ToString();
```

Comment: This returns the regex for GB regardless of the isoCode value

Comment: Have a +1 because you lead me to the eventual solution though I think the `Any()` is the problem with your query ;)

Comment: You'll need to add a `.Single().ToString()` to the end of the query but yep this works too :) cheers

Comment: :) I was mislead by the original code filtering postalcodedata instances, not postcoderegex instances. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I was only checking against the first matched element:

```
return (from n in xml.Descendants("postalCodeData").Elements("postCodeRegex")
        where n.Attribute("territoryId").Value == isoCode
        select n.Value).Single().ToString();
```